# Can't limit number of files and save it to database, Image uploader Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

first of all Im really new with Javascript and lets tell you what i need.

I have this code to make an image uploader to resize it on client-side and works perfect, made by [Joel Vardy](https://joelvardy.com/writing/javascript-image-upload). But I need to limint the number of images to upload by 10. I can't figured it out how to do it... also i can't find a way to host the image links on the Database via php

The HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Upload Photos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
<head>
<body>

    <h1>Upload Photos</h1>

    <form>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
        <div class="photos">

        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="./upload.js"></script>

</body>
```

The JS

```
document.querySelector('form input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function(event){
var files = event.target.files;

// Iterate through files
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    // Ensure it's an image
    if (files[i].type.match(/image.*/)) {

        // Load image
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

                // Add elemnt to page
                var imageElement = document.createElement('div');
                imageElement.classList.add('uploading');
                imageElement.innerHTML = '<span class="progress"><span></span></span>';
                var progressElement = imageElement.querySelector('span.progress span');
                progressElement.style.width = 0;
                document.querySelector('form div.photos').appendChild(imageElement);

                // Resize image
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                    max_size = 1200,
                    width = image.width,
                    height = image.height;
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > max_size) {
                        height *= max_size / width;
                        width = max_size;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > max_size) {
                        width *= max_size / height;
                        height = max_size;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                // Upload image
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (xhr.upload) {

                    // Update progress
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                        var percent = parseInt(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                        progressElement.style.width = percent+'%';
                    }, false);

                    // File uploaded / failed
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status == 200) {

                                imageElement.classList.remove('uploading');
                                imageElement.classList.add('uploaded');
                                imageElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+xhr.responseText+')';

                                console.log('Image uploaded: '+xhr.responseText);

                            } else {
                                imageElement.parentNode.removeChild(imageElement);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Start upload
                    xhr.open('post', 'process.php', true);
                    xhr.send(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));

                }

            }

            image.src = readerEvent.target.result;

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }

}

// Clear files
event.target.value = '';
});
```

The PHP

```
$filename = md5(mt_rand()).'.jpg';
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$image = file_get_contents('data://'.substr($data, 5));
if ( ! file_put_contents('images/'.$filename, $image)) {
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
exit();
}
unset($data);
unset($image);
echo './images/'.$filename;
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: If you're new to Javascript, you probably should learn the basics first before you dive into extensive code like this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I should start learning some JS ... but I just need to solve this problem to finish my site! after that will have all the time learn!! :D

Answer (score 2):

To limit the script to only work with max 10 files, do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (i < 11){

    }
}
```

for the database, read about mysql and learn it.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help bro! ...Now if I click again the input, can add 10 more files and 10+... Try to play with the code but when I move or add new code then I cant upload... With php what I dont know is where to get the links i know some basic php

Comment: you can use var fd = new FormData(); and append the filename and get it in your php script. Instead of the php://input you can get the data from the post value if you do somehting like fd.append("file", blobOrFile); blobOrFile is the data of the image you want to send kind of.